# Host web cam in uwp app over asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, streaming, uwp, webcam

I have an asp.net web application and a universal windows platform application running on my laptop with a web cam.
I want to access the web cam from my asp.net web application.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access access camera from a web hosted UWP app, you can refer to [Create your Hosted Web App](https://microsoftedge.github.io/WebAppsDocs/en-US/win10/CreateHWA.htm). And you probably need to enable the `WebCam` and `MicroPhone` capabilities in UWP App's manifest file in some scenario.

If you want to make your web application can directly call the camera device without a UWP app, you can use some jQuery webcam plugin. For example, you can try [this one](http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/). But this can not be used from your UWP app.

In this case, if you want to access web cam both from hosted uwp app and your web app, you need to implement two procedures in your web app, one for hosted UWP app using WinRT API to call the camera, the other one for web app only.

Comment: The web app is hosted on another server. While the uwp app is running on my laptop with camera attached. Problem is that if some one visits that web app, he should be able to watch the video of camera on my laptop. does your solution implements this scenario?

Comment: @KhuramNawaz, I understand, your web app is connected to a web server. But are you saying that you want someone from other device open the web app, then he is able to watch the video from your pc/mobile's camera? My solution is only for both apps to call the camera of the local device you are using.

Comment: Now you understood it right. Actually I dont want to call the camera from local device. To do it more clear, let me give you a full example.
"Person A" has a laptop with web camera and windows 10 uwp application running on it.
"Person B" has a laptop with a web browser.
"Person C" is a web server running an asp.net website.

These three are not connected locally in any way.
Now "Person B" can visit that website to watch the camera of "Person A".

That is what I want.

Comment: Geng - MSFT
will you look upon my comment?

Comment: @KhuramNawaz, I looked, I don't think it can be done in UWP.

Comment: @Geng - MSFT ok no worries. will you suggest me any alternative solutions please?